# Math: How to type bigg | (divider)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have a difficulty in typing dividers in following math.[image] It is very much appreciated if someone can give me a solution. Please find below my trying, which does not fully show the desired output with the incorrent length of dividers (trying 1) and unwanted vertical spaces (trying 2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

First Trying:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f( x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}}
\bigg|_{ x_{1}= 0}}{\partial x_{2}} \bigg|_{ x_{2}= 0}}{\partial x_{3}}\
\bigg|_{ x_{3}= 0}=\dfrac{A}{B}$$

Second Trying:
$$
\left.\dfrac{
\left.\dfrac{
\left.\dfrac{\partial f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}}\right|_{x_{1}=0}}
{\partial x_{2}}\right|_{x_{2}=0}}{\partial x_{3}}\right|_{x_{3}=0}=\dfrac{A}{B}
$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variant of an [answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606336/4427). Feel free to change the name of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\akzoboxA}
\newsavebox{\akzoboxB}

\newcommand{\uglyeval}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\akzoboxA{$#1$}%
  \sbox\akzoboxB{%
    $\left.\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace
     {\begin{gathered}\usebox\akzoboxA\end{gathered}}
    \right|_{#2}$%
  }%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\akzoboxA-\ht\akzoboxB}{\usebox\akzoboxB}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\[
\uglyeval{\dfrac{
  \uglyeval{\dfrac{
    \uglyeval{\dfrac{\partial f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial x_1}}{x_1=0}
  }{\partial x_2}}{x_2=0}
}{\partial x_3}}{x_3=0}
=\frac{A}{B}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m much more impressed by the fact that you managed to print a true emoji on TeX.SX. 

Comment: Many thanks! It works flawlessly and is convenient to extend up to any level.

Comment: Hi, egreg. there are very slight differences among the top posititions of the dividers. It is very small matter. But I wonder whether a simple modification can fix it?

Comment: @RomalpaAkzo I noticed that, but I wouldn’t recommend such notation anyway.

Comment: @egreg, manually adding `\vspcace{-1.8pt}` after `\begin{gathered}` gives me an acceptable quality. Honestly, I still feel a little uncomfortablity using such notation, but sofar find no better alternatives. Once again, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

How about this dirty hack woth `blkarray`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{r|l}
\dfrac{%
\left.\dfrac{
\left.\dfrac{\partial f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}}\right|_{x_{1}=0}}
{\partial x_{2}}\right|_{x_{2}=0}}{\partial x_{3}}&_{\rule{0pt}{3ex}\mkern-10mu x_{3}=0} =\dfrac{A}{B}
\end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Bernard. I find it almost perfect for `\partial x_3` fraction. May I ask whether it is possible to do the same trick with `\partial with x_2` too?

Comment: It seems more complicated. You want to delete the blank space below the numerator?

Comment: Yes, I hope to delete all blanks which appear not necessary . Since I have numerous equations like that, even some of them have up to 7 levels or more, the blanks would affect significantly to the beauty of the equation. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to find a solution, but a first try seem to show problems in nesting `blockarray`s