# Extra vertical space in fraction

Tags: fractions, vertical-spacing

If I compile this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[\left\lvert\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}t\,\mathrm
        dt}C\right\rvert\]
\end{document}
```

what I get is:

[image]

That vertical space below the letter `C` makes no sense. What is it due to? How to get rid of it?

Comment: What's the problem with the more natural `\left|\frac{1}{C}\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt\right|`?

Comment: @egreg Nothing! Of course it is more natural. Nevertheless, I would like to know where does that vertical space come from.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` make delimiters to grow until they cover the inner formula and they become symmetric with respect to the formula axis.

Comment: @egreg Thank you; I was unaware of the fact that the delimiters become symmetric with respect to the formula axis. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: It is possible to remove the vertical spacing  using  the `vmatrix` environment in the place of the pair `\lvert … \rvert`, but the result is not particularly æsthetic…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `\left<ldelim><math>\right<rdelim>`, TeX will measure the inner `<math>` and extend the two delimiters so as to cover the `<math>` and be *symmetric* with respect to the formula axis (where the main fraction line sits).

This is by design.

You might overcome the issue with some acrobatics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\jcsboxA}
\newsavebox{\jcsboxB}

\newcommand{\uglyabs}[1]{%
  \sbox\jcsboxA{$#1$}%
  \sbox\jcsboxB{$\left|\begin{gathered}\usebox\jcsboxA\end{gathered}\right|$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\jcsboxA-\ht\jcsboxB}{\usebox\jcsboxB}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\uglyabs{\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt}{C}}
\qquad \left|\frac{1}{C}\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt\right|
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that you know how to do it, avoid it.

Comment: Why not use vmatrix like Bernard mentions in a comment? Seems a lot easier

Comment: @daleif Because it doesn't work, that's why. The main fraction line should sit on the formula axis, not somewhere random. For an isolated formula, it seems to work, but not in context.

Comment: Oh, so there's a difference on how they are implemented because the bmatrix and pmatrix worked the last time I tried

Comment: @daleif They will center the whole  block with respect to the formula axis. Here's a picture if I add `\qquad\begin{vmatrix}<the formula>\end{vmatrix}` [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9iJi.png)

Comment: Ahh right, your example still have the line in the fraction in the same place

Comment: @daleif I not known this :-(..in fact I have also tried without to look the comments: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

        
\[\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}t\,\mathrm{d}t}C\end{vmatrix}\]
\end{document}`